# Removing Contents from div elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove contents from 2 div elements without removing the div itself.

```
<div id='test'>

content I want to remove

    <div id='childDiv'>

      content I want to remove

   </div>

</div>
```

I want to keep childDiv and test div but removing their contents. How do I do that?

`$('#test').empty()` will remove `childDiv` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about storing the childDiv then empty the parent, then put the inner child back?

```
$('#test').html($('#childDiv').html()) // didn't quite work

// this clears both divs and leaves only the structure
$('#test').html($('#childDiv').html(""));
```

jsFiddle, check the resulting black line with chrome, inspect. http://jsfiddle.net/tbspn/

Comment: @Adam.. This might work for the current structure.. But what if it has one more nested div..

Comment: @Sushanth Then that's a different question with an appropriately different, possibly more complex, answer and not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `.contents()`  and `.filter()` functions to filter them away..

```
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType != 1
    }).remove();
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3XjeE/)**

**[Extra Nesting](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3XjeE/1/)**

`return this.nodeType != 1` will select all the Non-Element type nodes and removing them from the **DOM.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is JavaScript way to do it:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('childDiv').innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').html('');
```

clears all internal markup too.

Comment: He stated in his question that he doesn't want to empty the child div.

Comment: Oops, my comment is actually wrong, I changed part of the wording without changing the rest, so it reads wrong. It should have said, "..doesn't want to remove the child div."

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$('#test').text('');

$('#childDiv').text('');
```